# Do I need a second US visa waiver to re-enter after a short trip from the US to Canada?

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, australian-citizens, eta

I'm an Australian passport holder, travelling with my family to the US for 1 month, including 3 days in Canada. I have the US Visa Waiver Program, as well as the Canadian eTA visa waiver to enter Canada.

I will visit Niagara Falls in Canada for 3 days, June 20-23, by air, and going back to the US to be in New York from June 23-26.

Do I need to get another visa waiver to re-enter the US from Canada?

Comment: Maybe your answer is already on one of the [Niagara Falls questions on this site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=niagara+falls)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what airport are you flying into on the way to Niagara Falls, Canada? I think the airport on the Canadian side is VFR-only and only accommodates private planes. The closest commercial airports are on the US side of the river (IAG, BUF), if you are traveling through one of those your border crossings will be at the land border.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to get another visa waiver?

No, you don't.  On the other hand, the border officer *can* grant you a fresh visa waiver when you re-enter the US.  From your point of view, however, it makes no difference.

All *you* really need to worry about is having valid [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) authorization.  If your ESTA application is approved, the resulting authorization is valid for two years, or until your passport expires, whichever is shorter.  It can be used for an unlimited number of entries while it is valid.

Historically, the visa waiver program (VWP) has been around far longer than ESTA.  People often confuse the two, since ESTA is far more visible to travelers than the VWP.  It may not be obvious to you, therefore, that you actually receive your visa waiver from the immigration officer who stamps your passport.  Whether the US considers the second entry a new waiver or a continuation of the first one is not significant to you.

The VWP does have rules about traveling to Canada that can be of concern to some visitors.  These rules are designed to prevent people from using Canada to extend their VWP stay in the US beyond the 90-day limit.  Since your entire trip in North America doesn't even come close to that limit, you do not need to be concerned about these rules.

There is of course a small chance that a border officer would question you about your plans to determine whether you are trying to abuse those rules.  It would therefore be a good idea to be able to show your entire itinerary when you return to the US, in case the officer presses the point.  But the usual principle applies: don't volunteer anything; don't hide anything.